# fetch array and put it in my formatted HTML style

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting company interested in from my db which is something like this in my table `Actor,Chief,Doctor` so I used `explode` to make it as an array I need to put every items on this `array` in my `HTML` style to be something like this

[image]

as you can see from my image I need to make Actor has 50 point and then Chief has 40 point and so on

this is my `PHP` and `HTML` code

```
<?php
    $getInterested = $db->prepare("SELECT interest_in FROM employer_basic_info WHERE id=?");
    $getInterested->bind_param('i', $company);
    if ($getInterested->execute()) {
        $result = $getInterested->get_result();
        while ($i = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $companyInterested=$i->interest_in;
            $tat= (explode(',', $companyInterested));
            ?>

            <div class="f_left  width_100per">
                <ul class="cbp-ntaccordion f_left width_100per">
                    <li>
                        <h3 class="cbp-nttrigger font20px"><?php echo $i->interest_in ?>
                            <div title="Number of CV's" class="number3 f_left">50</div>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="cbp-ntcontent cbp-ntcontentMahmoud">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="mainTable2 f_left margin_24pxBm">
                                        <div class="tablehHeader2"><span
                                                class="fieldOne2 width_35per">Employee name</span>
                                            <span class="fieldTWo2 width_20per">English Test</span> <span
                                                class="fieldThree2 width_20per">Soft Skills Test</span> <span
                                                class="fieldFour2 width_20per">IQ Test</span></div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="fieldOneDes2 width_35per"><a href="#">Mahmoud mamdoh
                                                        mohamed</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fieldTWoDes2 width_20per"><a href="#" class="browenLink">10/10</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fieldThreeDes2 width_20per">2/10</div>
                                                <div class="fieldThreeDes2 width_20per">N/A</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="fieldOneDes2 width_35per"><a href="#">PHP Web Developer</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fieldTWoDes2 width_20per"><a href="#" class="browenLink">10/10</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fieldThreeDes2 width_20per">2/10</div>
                                                <div class="fieldThreeDes2 width_20per">N/A</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="fieldOneDes2 width_35per"><a href="#">PHP Web Developer</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fieldTWoDes2 width_20per"><a href="#" class="browenLink">10/10</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fieldThreeDes2 width_20per">2/10</div>
                                                <div class="fieldThreeDes2 width_20per">N/A</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
<?php echo $i->interest_in ?>
```

with

> ```
>    <?php echo $tat[0]; ?>
> ```

or you can also do a simple formatting for friendly use.

> ```
> list($actor,$chief,$doctor) = explode(',',$companyInterested);
> ```

// If $tat variable is mixed , then you have to search for a value, Actor in your case

use

> `$actor = array_search('Actor', $tat); // Will search for actor and return key`

use it with:

```
<?php echo $tat[$actor]; ?>
```

Looping array:

```
$result = implode('<br/>', explode(',', $companyInterested));
```

Comment: yea I need something like this but what about the rest of the items on the array

Comment: what is coming from database is variable maybe it's four items maybe two it's not fixed

Comment: use $key = array_search('Actor', $tat); // Will search for actor and return key , then use it with  <?php echo $tat[$key]; ?>

Comment: yes I need to loop the array can you please edit your answer and show me example

Comment: I think I got it thanks for the idea `foreach($tat as $key){
                echo "$key<br />\n";
            }`

Answer (score 1):

I think here you can find how to accesss your values

```
$companyInterested='Actor,Chief,Doctor';

list($Actor,$Chief,$Doctor)= explode(',', $companyInterested); //option 1

 echo $Actor; echo $Chief; echo $Doctor;


$tat= explode(',', $companyInterested);  //option 2

print $tat[0]; print $tat[1]; print $tat[2];
```

if the size of an array is not fixed then you can use option 2 and initialize value like $i befor start while loop as follows

```
$i=0;
while($value == $variale){
//some codes
$tat= explode(',', $companyInterested);
print "<div> $tat[$i] </div>";
//continue
$i++; }
```

or you can even loop it.

```
while($value == $variale){
//some codes
$tat= explode(',', $companyInterested);
forech($tat as $value){
print "<div> $value </div>"; }
//continue
$i++; }
```